# Is there a way to fetch CMS Content from Apex or Lightning Component?

Tags: community-builder

I am trying to dynamically fetch content (HTML markup) from a CMS Content item.

I understand CMS Content is in beta, but is there a way via Apex or LWC/Aura where I can get the content from a specific CMS Content item?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is CMS Connect only for external CMS? We have internal CMS data that I'd like to retrieve. From my understanding, CMS Connect is only for accessing 3rd party CMS content (i.e. from Wordpress).

Comment: We are trying to do the same and the docs don't mention this although CMS is generally available now.